# Sed adds x27 instead single quote

Tags: sed

I'm trying to replace a line of text with a single quote using `/x27` in my router device to re-configure wifi settings.

**The command that I use**

`sed -i 's/option ssid.*/option ssid \x27test\x27/g' /some/file`

**The output after I execute above command on my computer(ubuntu 18)**

`option ssid 'test123'`

**The output after I execute above command on my router**

`option ssid x27test123x27`

**Expected output should be**

`option ssid 'test123'`

So my code is not working properly on the router. How do I achieve this using /x27?
Note: I'm executing this script in a shell script and \x27test\x27 is actually \x27$OPTARG\x27

You can find my full code [here](https://ybin.me/p/4f55e696aa1b87f3#kEpaZuPsrrRS20B165ABnNFeKWwHv22hJrpOdqe0aIc=)

Comment: escape the \x27 ?, so make it \\x27

Comment: Please add sample input and your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: The output should look like my computer's output: `option ssid 'test'` and @hootnot I tried already didn't worked.

Comment: most likely you are using `\x27$OPTARG\x27` inside double quotes right? if so, you can use single quote instead of `\x27`

Comment: may be add which shell you are using for the script, `bash` or something else?

Comment: @Sundeep Yes I'm using inside double quotes and I tried that too but no luck. I'm using shell script. The weird thing script works on my computer perfectly but my in my router it's not working. Here is the full code:  https://ybin.me/p/4f55e696aa1b87f3#kEpaZuPsrrRS20B165ABnNFeKWwHv22hJrpOdqe0aIc=

Comment: @Cyrus I've updated the question.

Comment: Please tell us which shell your router is using. Obviously that shell is different from `bash`. Maybe you can work around the quoting by using different quoting: `sed -i 's/option ssid.*/option ssid '"'"'test'"'"'/g' /some/file` or by using Perl: `perl -i -pe "s/^option ssid .*/option ssid 'test'/g" /some/file`

Comment: I'm using `sh and ash` in my router and unfortunately, your advice didn't work too. So I fix my problem with: `sed -i 's/option ssid.*/option ssid '"'"'"'$OPTARG'"'"'"'/g'` the reason that why I want to do it with \x27, quotes hurting my eyes. It's not easy to read the code with quotes... Thanks in advice anyway

Comment: If `\x27test\x27` is actually `\x27$OPTARG\x27` then you are not executing the script in your question `sed -i 's/option ssid.*/option ssid \x27test\x27/g' /some/file`. If you want help debugging some code then show the actual code you want help to debug in your question, don't show us some different code that you think kinda looks like it. Asking for help because `My car won't start` and then later telling us `Oh by the way it's actually a horse` is not well received.

Comment: @EdMorton Thank you for your answer and I already added my full code in comments but I think I should add it to the question. Sorry my bad.

Comment: Your question still says "The command that I use..." and then shows us some other command than the one you're asking for help with. [edit] your question to simply show us THE command you're asking for help with (and make sure it's a [mcve]). Don't provide links to other sites btw, it's just not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can double quote Your sed command and then use single quotes inside:

```
sed -i "s/option ssid.*/option ssid 'test'/g" /some/file
```

Comment: I got this error `./setwifi.sh: 10: ./setwifi.sh: key.*/option: not found
./setwifi.sh: 6: ./setwifi.sh: ssid.*/option: not found
`

Answer (score 0):

In a comment you said your real code is:

```
sed -i 's/option ssid.*/option ssid '"'"'"'$OPTARG'"'"'"'/g'
```

That should be written more correctly and concisely as:

```
sed -i 's/\(option ssid\).*/\1 '"'$OPTARG'"'/g'
```

Look:

```
$ echo 'hi option ssid question' | sed 's/\(option ssid\).*/\1 '"'$RANDOM'"'/'
hi option ssid '5203'
```

Given [your feedback to a different answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53865427/sed-adds-x27-instead-single-quote?noredirect=1#comment94589277_53870984) it sounds like the version of sed you're running requires a backup file name between the `-i` and the `s/...`. Otherwise there's a bug somewhere earlier in your shell script or `$OPTARG` contains forward slashes or backreferences.

Comment: When I use your solution the shell reading $OPTARG as a string not a variable or argument in visual studio and if I run the shell I got this error in my teriminal `./setwifi.sh: 22: ./setwifi.sh: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
`

Comment: I've no idea what `the shell reading $OPTARG as a string not a variable or argument in visual studio` means. Did you read what I said under my script?